# How do I get extra powerful paralysis enchantments?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did the restoration loop and now I can one shot anything, level any skill to 100, send enemies up to level 70 million running is fear, etc. But, when I try to get an extra powerful paralysis enchantment, it says "chance to paralyze opponent for 2 seconds" and the only thing changed by my ring that grants +[big number]% to enchanting is the number of charges, which is huge. How can I make is say, "chance to paralyze opponent for [big number] seconds?